# Stuck on stubborn method

Tags: java, methods

I cannot find why this method goes from the first line directly to last without running what is in-between, mostly likely something very simple.

```
public void addAdress() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to add " + this.getName() + "´s Adress?Y or N?");
    afirmativeanswer = true;

    while (afirmativeanswer) {
        answer = input.nextLine();
        if (answer.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter " + this.getName() + "´s Adress!");
            answer = input.nextLine();
            this.setAdress(answer);
            afirmativeanswer = false;
        } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("You choose not to add " + this.getName() + "´s Adress!");
            afirmativeanswer = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter y or n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cant put any input ,code runs directly from the first system.out.println to the last on the else statment

Comment: What does the first line print ?

Comment: This piece of code should work. Maybe something wrong with your input scanner. can you give some more code.

Comment: This piece of code actually works, given `input = new Scanner(System.in)`. The problem is not in the above code. Voting to close.

Comment: Code works good... (assuming input is `new Scanner(System.in)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `input.next()`instead of `input.nextLine()`
the reason is that the nextLine() method will return the next line in the buffer, so it won't ask you for an input every time 
for more information check the Scanner documentation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Not true, the above code works fine without those `next()` if user is pressing 'enter' after each input, which is normal behaviour in console apps

Comment: Yes it worked with input.next() ,although i can´t understand why i have 3 more methods just like these one on my code and all work fine with input.nextLine ,i even copy the code above and pasted in another program and it also run well ,so problem solved ....but still confused!

Answer (score 0):

check: `System.err.println("'" + answer + "'");` just after `answer = input.nextLine();`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10330073)

Comment: Additionally, it is always safer to do `System.err.println("'" + answer + "'");` - the `'`s will make whitespace or newline problems much more evident in the output.

Comment: @Danielson   it provides a mean to detect what (and perhaps where) is the problem, since the code works, as says tucuxi.

Comment: I agree printlns are good... And helpful for debugging... Your answer is more like a comment, since it can help to debug the problem, but it (in itself) is not the answer

Comment: I did System.err.println("'" + answer + "'"); like you say guilaume girod-vitouchk  and i got this two things ´´ in red right before the code jumps to the last System.out.println,what does that means?

Comment: Normally, it means the function receives empty line. Then problem is in input, not int function . Try    @tucuxi    method : input = new Scanner(System.in)